# Aero disabled in Windows 7 after installing LogMeIn

Tags: windows-7, aero

I have a [Dell Inspiron 1520](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Inspiron#Inspiron_1525_.28Inspiron_15.29) ([Intel Core 2 Duo T5250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_2_microprocessors#.22Merom.22.2C_.22Merom-2M.22_.28standard-voltage.2C_65_nm.29) / 2 GB RAM / [Nvidia 8600M GT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_8_Series#GeForce_8500_and_8600_Series) running 190.89 drivers / Windows 7 Ultimate). I had recently installed the [LogMeIn Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/logmein/), so that I can control and access my system. After a system restart, I find that Aero is disabled. On clicking on `Troubleshoot problems with Aero` link, I am told "To allow Aero effects to be displayed, close any problems that use mirror drivers such as [Live Mesh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live_Mesh) or [Windows Remote Assistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Remote_Assistance)".

I presumed this was because of LogMeIn drivers, however uninstalling it has no effect. I do not use Live Mesh, and Windows Remote Assistance either. What can I do to have Aero enabled again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Device Manager, disable the "LogMeIn Mirror Driver" under "Display adapters" and reboot.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Wonder why the uninstall did not remove the drivers.

Comment: because LogMeIn is a useless PoS (piece of software), i wonder why people using it at all when they can have Teamviewer for free.

Comment: Well for one I can access it from my workplace. I can't access my system from work using Teamviewer.

Comment: run the Teamviewer Host Server as windows service on your home computer, never failed me. unless you're not allowed to use Teamviewer at work, of course.

Comment: @Molly that's the problem, we are not allowed to use Teamviewer, Logmein is, however, allowed.

Comment: not even the portable version? works from USB and doesn't have to be installed on your work computer?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I was cut off in a session by a power outage, simply log-in to the machine remotely and disconnect properly, Aero should magically reappear.