# Aero in Windows 7 Not Working

Tags: windows-7, drivers, aero, vncserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Win7 Aero disabled due to mirror drivers following TightVNC use, cannot re-enable](https://superuser.com/questions/160245/win7-aero-disabled-due-to-mirror-drivers-following-tightvnc-use-cannot-re-enabl)

I'm using a Windows 7 laptop, and a few months ago I installed a VNC server/client program. It seems like a feature of the program changed a driver in a way that turned off Aero. However, I haven't been able to reenable Aero again. I don't want to uninstall this VNC software, I barely even use the VNC server (mainly the client, and the client side part shouldn't change my graphics drivers). When I Googled it and found one of those auto-tech-support type programs from Microsoft for solving problems with enabling Aero, it said something about needing to change my drivers that weren't letting Aero run (I forget the exact words, I can find it again if that would be useful). Also, this computer has run Aero before, with this same edition of Windows 7, so it's not that I don't have Aero in this copy of Windows and it's not that the hardware is incompatible. Any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 2):

You mean this one?

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Troubleshoot-problems-with-Windows-Aero

> Why does Aero occasionally stop working?
>   Some older programs might be incompatible with Aero. When you run the program, Aero might stop working for as long as the program is running. Closing the program should restore Aero. To avoid this problem, check with the manufacturer of the program to see if there is a version available that is compatible with Windows Vista.

.

Comment: Yeah, Microsoft Fix It, forgot the name of it.
Well, when I was using Tight VNC, I guess that could be the case. However, I still had that problems when my VNC server (and client) was closed (it was no longer in the system tray, and the server sits in the tray when it's running). Coul it be possible that one of the system services it runs always runs when the computer is on, and that is why it's always blocking Aero from working?

Comment: Sometimes when a program runs it causes aero to stop working, it is supposed to revert back when you close the program, but sometimes it does not, such as in your case. Did the MS fixit work?

Comment: No, it said something about me having to close drivers. I can give you the exact error message if that would be helpful. Should I try it again after trying to kill processes of this program in task manager? Or would I be better off fully uninstalling the server?

Comment: I would uninstall the problematic software, buts thats just me.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'll try this when I have the chance.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem: [Win7 Aero disabled due to mirror drivers following TightVNC use, cannot re-enable](https://superuser.com/questions/160245/win7-aero-disabled-due-to-mirror-drivers-following-tightvnc-use-cannot-re-enable)