# Full Uninstall winvnc.exe

Tags: windows-7, vnc, tightvnc, ultravnc

This computer (Windows 7) has not been able to run Windows Aero after I installed some VNC software, UltraVNC and TightVNC. I want to get Aero back, and Microsoft Fix It tells me that it can't be turned on because of mirror drivers (this edition includes Aero, and I had it working well before), which I managed to learn can come from winvnc.exe, which is installed by both programs.

I would like to uninstall winvnc.exe and the service from this computer. I messed with the command line a little (I know, I aws being careful), but I couldn't get anywhere, I'm a total beginner with the command line.

Can someone please help me remove the exe file and the service, so the mirror drivers are disabled and I can use Aero again? I don't need the VNC servers (I couldn't get them to work anyway), but if keeping the clients is possible that would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem: [Win7 Aero disabled due to mirror drivers following TightVNC use, cannot re-enable](https://superuser.com/questions/160245/win7-aero-disabled-due-to-mirror-drivers-following-tightvnc-use-cannot-re-enable)